# Data transformation

Tags: time-series, data-transformation, bounds, state-space-models

I was writing with a question regarding a time-varying state space model of the form:
\begin{align}
y(t) &= \mu_1(t) + A(t)x(t) + v(t);         &v(t) &\sim (0, R(t))  \\
x(t) &= \mu_2(t) + \Phi(t)\!\times\!x(t-1) + s(t); &s(t) &\sim (0, Q(t))
\end{align}
$x(t)$ is of the form: $x(t) = \log[1-X(t)]$

obviously,
$$ 
 |X(t)| \leq 1  \\
\Rightarrow x(t) \text{ lies in } (-\infty, \log(2) ]
$$
Could anyone suggest a transformation that I could use, so that $x(t)$ becomes unbounded?

Comment: I took the liberty of formatting your post using the $\LaTeX$ markup our site affords. Please ensure it still says what you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

If $-1 < X(t) < 1$, then 
$T(X(t)) = sign(X(t)) \exp(1/\log(|X(t)|))$ would be unbounded, i.e. $(-\infty, +\infty)$.